# Getting servlet path by using <c:url> or ${pageContext.request} in InternalResourceViewResolver of Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm using `InternalResourceViewResolver` from Spring to render view existing in `/WEB-INF/view`. I also use JSTL in view. Now the problem comes after change `<url-pattern>` of `DispatcherServlet` in `web.xml`.

I tried to get servlet path by `${pageContext.request.servletPath}` but it returns `/WEB-INF/view/skel/welcome.jsp` which is the path from WEB-INF directory, while `request.getServletPath()` returns `/h2o` inside of controller Java code. `<% out.print(request.getServletPath()); %>` also returns `/WEB-INF/view/skel/welcome.jsp` in view file (`/WEB-INF/view/skel/welcome.jsp`).

It seems to come from difference between request instances in controller Java code & JSP view file. Request is instance of `org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest` in JSP view file, but it's instance of `org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade` in controller Java code.

Until now, fortunately, we install it alone and didn't need to care about `<uri-patter>` or servlet path. But this project requires integration with other system so getting servlet path from view file to map correct URL of some menu or form action target.

Do you have any idea to get correct servlet path (`/h2o`) from view file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path']} should work for you as well.

Comment: my god, how much we must dig to find a simple info like this?! Why there's no "getServletPath()" method or something, I was struggling to find this. Thank you sir

Answer (score 1):

Have the controller code put the result of request.getServletPath() into a variable in request scope, and then reference that with jstl in your JSP.

Comment: Thank you. What I wanted is little bit different but I can solve the problem in similar way.

I set request instance from Java code as a attribute of request named `request` and I access it with `${request.servletPath}` from JSP view file -- `request.setAttribute("request", request)`.